# Assign lowest of two values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was curious to know if there is a way in Javascript or JQuery to make a variable equal the lowest of a set of values simply.

So assuming I have:

```
X = 1
Y = 2

Var Z = lowest of X or Y
```

I know I could do an if statement that basically reads

```
if(X < Y){
    Z = X
} else {
    Z = Y
}
```

I was mainly just curious if something existed to do this in one line.

Thanks!

Comment: I need to ask harder questions :p I get too many correct answers and don't know who to mark as correct lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `ternary` operator.

```
let z = x < y ? x : y
```

Another method is to use `Math.min` function.

```
let z = Math.min(x, y);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `Math.min` function: `Math.min(X, Y)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary operator.

```js
let X = 1;
let Y = 2;

let Z = (X<Y?X:Y);
console.log(Z);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what you need:

`var Z = X < Y ? X : Y;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

```
X = 1;
Y = 2;
Z = Math.min(X, Y);
```

or

```
X = 1;
Y = 2;
Z = (X < Y) ? X : Y;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```
var z = x < y ? x : y
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var X = 1;
var Y = 2;
document.write(Math.min(X,Y));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
let Z = Math.min(X, Y);
```